Does the zero vector have to be composed by zeroes only?
I was going over the ten axioms for a problem with vector addition and multiplication defined below where V is the set of all positive real numbers.
$x + y   =   xy$   Addition
$cx   =   xc$      Scalar multiplication
I am a bit confused about Axiom 4. It says that for every u in V, u + the zero vector must equal u. For this set, would the zero vector be 1?
My line of reasoning was:
u $+ 1 = u*1 = $u
Is the zero vector also referred to as the additive identity? Does it not have to be all 0s strictly? I think the name "zero vector" is kind of throwing me off.

Don't get hung up on notation.  You are correct that $1$ is the only possible "additive identity" under this operation.  Of course, you still have to check all the other axioms.

@holp Yes, you are right. The "zero-vector" for your vector space $V$ is $1$. Some textbooks will use the notation $\mathbf 0_V = 1$. Indeed, a vector doesn't "have to strictly be all 0's" (and for that matter, doesn't even need to have "entries" in the usual sense) in order to be the "zero-vector". And yes, the "zero-vector" is the same as the "additive identity"

The more elementary examples in the Mathematics Educators SE question/answers Big list of "interesting" abstract vector spaces might be helpful.

The 'zero' vector is exactly any object that satisfies the axiom you described. In fact, part of the definition of a vector space $(V,F,+,\cdot )$ is that $(V, +)$ is an Abelian group. So you are absolutely correct that the zero vector and 'additive identity' are one in the same thing.
Note however that we call it the 'additive identity' because the operation is typically denoted with the plus symbol, and we define it to be 'vector addition'. But these are just naming conventions - there is no restriction placed on what the operation must 'be', only that it ends up satisfying the axioms to be a vector space.
If you are a little familiar with abstract algebra, it can provide some instructive examples: for example, consider the Abelian group (I'll leave you to show it is so) $(G,+)$, where I define $G = \{e,o\}$, and $+$ is defined such that $e+e = e, e+o = o + e = o, o + o = e$. Then here $e$ is the zero element of this group, which we can also call the 'additive identity'.
The example above is really just saying that $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ is an Abelian group. But the point I was trying to make is that the zero element could simply be denoted by '$e$'. It's just a label for an object in your set that satisfies the relevant axioms/definitions.
Having said that, there is of course some sense in denoting these objects as "zero". In some manner, they capture the 'quality' of the number zero you are likely thinking of. In essence, we are abstracting the notion of what it means to be 'zero'. It just turns out that the most familiar and intuitive notion of zero is precisely the number (integer/real/complex etc) zero. But the quality of 'zero-ness' can be extracted out to other settings, and that's exactly what the group axiom definition does.

Here's another example over the reals. The group $\Bbb R_{>0}$ of positive real numbers under multiplication forms a vector space over the reals with scalar multiplication defined by taking powers. Here the zero vector is the number $1$.

@LukasHeger I really like that example, much nicer than mine actually to illustrate the point I was trying to make!
